# Having trouble with htaccess (one parameter that shows up on every page)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble with rewriting the url on a page. I am just an apache noob so this could be a silly question, but here goes.
This is the apache:

> RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/ ?page=$1 [NC,L]
>
> RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/ ?page=product&ID=$1 [NC,L]

I have a variable page=shop (product, contact,etc) where the url looks like

> www.example/shop/

I am using GET to show the pages, but when I type something like

> "www.example/product/1/" ("www.example/?page=product&ID=1")

I can not get the product id. Also if I delete the first rewrite rule, than I get the product id, but the pages dont work (obviously)

How could I check, if there is a secont parameter that goes with the page=products?

Any help would be appreciated ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of your rewriting rules. They are processed from top to bottom. So you have two alternatives:

Reorder your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?product/([0-9]+)/ ?page=product&ID=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-z]+)/ ?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Make the first rule more specific:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-z]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?product/([0-9]+)/? ?page=product&ID=$1 [NC,L]
```

I also made some other minor changes to improve the robustness of your rule set:

- use `^/?` in the pattern to make your rules work in dynamic configuration files (as you currently do) *and* in the real http servers host configuration which should always be preferred if possible.
- use `/?` for the trailing slash to make it optional.
- using `[...a-zA-Z]` in the pattern together with the `NC` flag is redundant, obviously.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: awesome. Tanks i will get the rules inside the server. But i still have a problem. The "www.example/product/1/" works, but now all of the other pages like "www.example/shop/" dont work.

Comment: @NikolaKailCavaPopović Well, which alternative do you use? And what "other pages" are those?

Comment: For example I have a page "www.example/shop/" (www.example/?page=shop). So if the $_GET['page'] = "shop", the shop page with product listing will show up. This is how I include different pages in my index.php.

Comment: You did not answer to my questions, sorry.

Comment: OK so what do you mean as alternative? Other pages are just that, all other pagest that are not www.example.com/product/someID/. So contact page, product listing, home, etc. Because I am using GET to include content inside my index.php

Comment: Once more: which of the two alternatives above do you currently use and which does not allow to request those "other" pages? And about those "other" pages, so you refer to URLs like `www.example.com/contact/` and `www.example.com/home/`, right?

Comment: Thats right. I am using the second one you posted, the more specific one.

Comment: Whoops, I am sorry, I made a typo in that rule! I just corrected it, you need to use `$`, not `&` as a terminating anchor.

Comment: Its working great. Awsome tnx :D will try to learn more about rewrite ;)